# tabBarController and first Tab viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a tabBarNavigated Application. In second tab, I do something that works fine, but now I want to do something in the first Tab, so first I try to `NSLog` a string, but I get no reaction.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

If I add a label to the view, it will be displayed, but no reaction on my code.

if I start my app, i see this view, but i can't call any actions in this method, even if i change the tab, and go back to the first one, still no logs.

[image]

I try to NSlog in GehaltView

this is the mainWindow

[image]

viewWillAppear dosn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

The `-viewDidLoad` method is only called when your view is loaded. This method **will not be called again** unless the view gets unloaded, in which case `-viewDidUnload` will be called. A view can be unloaded if there is a memory issue, but otherwise they generally stick around.

If you want to trigger an action that happens every time the view appears, then you can use the `-viewWillAppear:` method instead. This method is called every time the view re-appears. You can track when the view disappears with `-viewWillDisappear`, and watch the two get called as you toggle between the two tabs.

Note also that `-viewDidLoad` may get called before the view appears, but `-viewWillAppear` will only be called when the view actually appears (or moments before, as the `will` indicates).

EDIT: The code should read

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"View Will Appear");
}
```

EDIT: This entire answer assumes that you have a subclass of `UIViewController`. It seems to me that you are by-passing using viewControllers, which in general is a bad idea.

Comment: i add a method -(void) viewWillAppear
{
     NSLog(@"TableView");
}, still no reaction.

Comment: this is a view what i see if i start my app, maybe a i have to do some another action... if I switch to tab 2, everything ist OK, but even i go back to tab 1, i Stil get no message

Comment: no stil nothing, maybe i try to explain my situation better. i wil add some screenshots to my question

Comment: @Fincha: Then something is seriously amiss with your code. This method, inside a `UIViewController`, will work as described.

Comment: you misspelled the method, `viewWillAppear:` - if you're not familiar with that, you need to read the [View Controller Programing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in interface builder i have to add a custom class to the forst tab.